# Exception while debugging Shims, UnitTestIsolationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

While using Shims, I get an exception while debugging.  While others have reported this issue, none of the fixes that I have found have helped.  This is the scenario.  Although I discovered this on a full size project, I can reproduce it on a simple project.  I only get this exception when using my work computer.  If I try it on a coworkers computer or my home computer, I do not get the error.

Windows 7, fully patched.
VS Ultimate 2012, Update 4.
Default Processor Architecture of x64.
No Typemock or other mocking framework installed (that I am aware of).
No run settings or test settings in the solution (have verified in explorer).

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
        }
    }
```

If I run the test normally, no issue.  However if I try to debug I get the exception on the using statement.

Exception:
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test
  Source=Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
       at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
       at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
       at MyLogTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyLogTest\MyLogTest\UnitTest1.cs:line 13
  InnerException:

(** user id XXXX'd out for security **).

If I take that failing project from my work computer and put it on my home computer (also VS Ultimate 2012, update 4, Windows 7) I do not get the error while debugging.

I tried doing a full uninstall of VS (including renaming the old VS folder in Program Files) and a fresh install, I still get the exception.

In desperation I turned on logging for Visual Studio.  The only significant difference that I noticed was the following in the log for devenv.TpTrace.log

Diagnostic: RockSteady initialized with the following extensions:

Diagnostic: Processing Queue .....

Diagnostic: Operation Dequeue : 'LoadPlaylistOperation'

Diagnostic: Operation left in the the queue: 1

Diagnostic:     'RunWithDebugFromContextOperation', hashcode:12788809

Diagnostic:

I tried looking for that "RockSteady" to see where it was coming from or what it is with no luck.  These lines do not appear on my home computer when I perform the same test.  I am thinking that there might be something installed on my machine from an SDK or something else that is causing an issue.  I don't know that those lines above are the source of the problem, it is just the only major difference I am seeing.

I've been stuck on this for several days now.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried launching VS in safe mode and running the tests? `Devenv.exe /SafeMode` or perhaps resetting your settings via `Devenv.exe /ResetSettings`?

Comment: I had tried both of those but good suggestions.  As a note, when I run SafeMode I cannot actually run tests or debug them.  Since I've never run SafeMode, is that normal?

Comment: I've never had to run safe mode myself, so I couldn't say. In the project properties, you are using the default "Start project" action and nothing under "Start Options", right?

Comment: Those are still available but what I am trying to debug is a unit test.  I will check to see if I can put the shim in regular code to test the SafeMode.

Comment: Tried in SafeMode but I think there is too much turned off.  I could not start debugger even when I tried to run it as a simple Console app.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
            }
        }

Comment: Are you using resharper? If so, make sure the 'Use Legacy Testrunner' value is not checked under Tools->Unit Testing -> MSTest

Comment: I had an older version of Resharper on my VS 2010 but had not installed it for 2012.  I removed it a few days ago to make sure that the Resharper in 2010 was not messing up the 2012 debugger somehow.  Good suggestion though.

Comment: Then at this point, I'd start weighing the costs/benefits of doing a full re-install of Win7 or trying to remove any apps/components that are on your work box but not home. No other suggestions from me.

Comment: Thanks.  I am heavily leaning towards doing a clean install of Windows as well.  I've beaten myself up enough over this.  A clean install would also remove the possibility of some artifact from 2010 interfering.

Comment: Is there any difference in the debug settings eg. break on exception types, symbol server etc. ?

Comment: No.  In fact, I imported my settings from a working machine to test.